# Connecting to wordpress MySQL database with Node.js

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, node.js

At the minute I'm just trying to connect to the database but I am getting a connection refused error.The database is from a wordpress site that was set up and I am trying to connect to that through Node using the node mysql driver - https://www.npmjs.org/package/mysql

The way the user's have looked at the database before was through phpmyadmin and im not sure what to use as the hostname for a database like this. i have tried using the server name given to me - cust-mysql-123-14 but that just gives me a address not found error obviously. The only other information i have about the server is this address;

linweb14.atlas.pipex.net

When i connect with that it then throws up this error;

```
error connecting: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/tp/Desktop/angular-seed/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:135:48)
at Protocol.handshake (/Users/tp/Desktop/angular-seed/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
at Connection.connect (/Users/tp/Desktop/angular-seed/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:108:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tp/Desktop/angular-seed/app/server.js:29:12)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
```

Heres the database bit of code in my .js file (replaced connection details);

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection(
{
host     : 'hidden',
user     : 'hidden',
password : 'hiddden',
database : 'hidden',
port     : 3000
}
);

connection.connect(function(err) {
 if (err) {
console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
return;
}

console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
});
```

Any ideas or advice on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: General port of mysql is 3306, why are you using 3000? Maybe external access to MySQL is not permitted and/or blocked via firewall?

Comment: Ah didnt actually know that that was the port for mysql. Tried it with it and still no luck.

I did find out though that it is being hosted by 123-reg who don't allow remote connections to the database :(